# Подскажите где ошибка в перевороте числа (Pascal ABC)

Tags: pascal, функции

```
function PowerA (x:integer; var k:integer):integer;
begin
  while x > 0 do
  begin
    write (x mod 10); // переворот нат числа
    x:= x div 10;
  end;
end;
begin
  var a,b:integer;
  Writeln ('введите число');
  readln (a); // а - это число, которое мы переводим
  write (PowerA (a,b));
end.
```

Если без функции, то все работает, с функцией в конце выдает ноль, например, ввожу 3456, а выдает 65430

Comment: эээ... а код вы сами писали? что у вас возвращает функция `PowerA`?

Comment: я только учусь. Хотел посмотреть как можно использовать функцию в программе. Как я понял из литературы при помощи функции можно провести подсчет, а потом вывести результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функции обычно используются иначе.

В Pascal функция возвращает результат. Возвращает она его через специальную переменную, имя которой совпадает с именем функции (или переменная result, в fpc). 
Тип возвращаемого значения определяется после двоеточия в объявлении функции. У вас он integer. В функцию передаются значения, необходимые для подсчёта результата.

В вашем случае у функции должен быть один параметр - число, которое необходимо "перевернуть". И из функции необходимо вернуть перевёрнутое число. Внутри функции вывод возможен - но в практических целях это почти бессмысленно.

Если вы хотите перевернуть число таким способом - вам лучше использовать процедуру.

0 у вас в конце - это вывод write (PowerA (a,b)), функция вернула 0, а write его вывела.

Замените стоку

write (PowerA (a,b))

на строку

PowerA (a,b);

и выведется верный результат.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо просто вызывать функцию, а не выводить ее возвращаемое значение, которое как видим есть 0. То есть так `PowerA (a,b);` вместо `write (PowerA (a,b));`. 
Если бы ваша функция набирала строку (или число), а потом возвращала результат, то вызов  `write (PowerA (a,b));` был бы правильным. Но у вас функция сама выводит результат по одной цифре и ничего не возвращает (точнее ничего осмысленного - в итоге возвращается ноль).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. сам бы тупил долго.

Comment: @user193840 пожалуйста. Если вопрос закрыт - примите один из ответов, отметив его галочкой (под количеством голосов за ответ).